# Scrape a large messy table from the web and put into a data frame

Tags: r, rvest, xml2

I'm trying to import the table at http://killedbypolice.net/ into R. The table is large and has merged cells, so it's not straightforward. The last step of my code never ends. How can I get the table into my R session?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
url <- "http://killedbypolice.net/"
# read in the web page
tmp1 <- read_html(url, options = "HUGE") 

# Extract the table from the web page, I used Chrome's inspector to
# identify the XPath here, following these instructions
# http://blog.corynissen.com/2015/01/using-rvest-to-scrape-html-table.html 
tmp2 <- html_nodes(tmp1, xpath='/html/body/center/font/font/font/font/font/font/table')

# Convert HTML table to a data frame 
tmp3 <- html_table(tmp2, fill = TRUE)
```

The problem is that the last line runs forever. I guess it's hanging on the merged cells?

Is there another way to get the HTML table into a data frame?

Comment: I think I've now got it worked out here: https://rpubs.com/benmarwick/scraping-kbp